# In python, how to parse a file into lists based on a specific value?

Tags: python, file, parsing, list

I have a large tab delimited text file, for example, call it john_file:

> 1 john1 23 54 54
> 2 john2 34 45 66
> 3 john3 35 43 54
> 4 john2 34 54 78
>
> 5 john1 12 34 65
> 6 john3 34 55 66

What's a quick way to parse this file into 3 lists based on name(john1, 2 or 3)?

```
fh=open('john_file.txt','r').readlines()
john1_list=[]
for i in fh:
 if i.split('\t')[1] == "john1":
  john1_list.append(i)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: did you aldready answer your own question? your solution seems to be be pretty quick

Comment: @Christian: Thanks for the quick response. In my code for this example, I would have to write 3 loops. In my actual file I have from john1 to john30 so I was looking for a more concise way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)

with open('john_file.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        fields = line.split('\t')
        d[fields[1]].append(line)
```

The individual lists are then in `d['john1']`, `d['john2']` etc

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
fh=open('john_file.txt','r').readlines()
john_lists={}
for i in fh:
    j=i.split('\t')[1]
    if j not in johns:
        john_lists[j]=[]
    johns[j].append(i)
```

This has the advantage of not depending on knowing in advance the possible values in the second column.

As others point out, you can also use the `defaultdict` to do

```
from collections import defaultdict
fh=open('john_file.txt','r').readlines()
john_lists=defaultdict(list)
for i in fh:
    j=i.split('\t')[1]
    johns[j].append(i)
```

Comment: If you set `john_lists` to `collections.defaultdict(list)`, then you won't need the if statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> a = defaultdict(list)
>>> for line in '''1 john1 23 54 54
... 2 john2 34 45 66
... 3 john3 35 43 54
... 4 john2 34 54 78
... 5 john1 12 34 65
... 6 john3 34 55 66
... '''.split('\n'):
...  data = filter(None, line.split())
...  if data:
...   a[data[1]].append(data)
... 
>>> data
[]
>>> a
defaultdict(<type 'list'>, {'john1': [['1', 'john1', '23', '54', '54'], ['5', 'john1', '12', '34', '65']], 'john2': [['2', 'john2', '34', '45', '66'], ['4', 'john2', '34', '54', '78']], 'john3': [['3', 'john3', '35', '43', '54'], ['6', 'john3', '34', '55', '66']]})
```

Answer (score 0):

littletable makes this kind of simple slicing and dicing easy, making a list of objects accessible/queryable/pivotable by attribute, like a mini-in-memory database, but with even less overhead than SQLite.

```
from collections import namedtuple
from littletable import Table

data = """\
 1 john1 23 54 54
 2 john2 34 45 66
 3 john3 35 43 54
 4 john2 34 54 78
 5 john1 12 34 65
 6 john3 34 55 66"""

Record = namedtuple("Record", "id name length width height")
def makeRecord(s):
    s = s.strip().split()
    # convert all but name to ints, and build a Record instance
    return Record(*(ss if i == 1 else int(ss) for i,ss in enumerate(s)))

# create a table and load it up 
# (if this were CSV data, would be even simpler)
t = Table("data")
t.create_index("id", unique=True)
t.create_index("name")
t.insert_many(map(makeRecord, data.splitlines()))

# get a record by unique key 
# (unique indexes return just the single record)
print t.id[4]
print

# get all records matching an indexed value 
# (non-unique index retrievals return a new Table)
for d in t.name['john1']:
    print d
print

# dump summary pivot tables
t.pivot('name').dump_counts()
print

t.create_index('length')
t.pivot('name length').dump_counts()
```

Prints:

```
Record(id=4, name='john2', length=34, width=54, height=78)

Record(id=1, name='john1', length=23, width=54, height=54)
Record(id=5, name='john1', length=12, width=34, height=65)

Pivot: name
john1       2
john2       2
john3       2

Pivot: name,length
           12      23      34      35   Total
john1       1       1       0       0       2
john2       0       0       2       0       2
john3       0       0       1       1       2
Total       1       1       3       1       6
```